# What are the best sites to get caught up on Calculus?

Tags: calculus

I'm going back to college this summer and will be taking engineering statistics and calculus based physics.  I dropped out of college about 4 years ago and took calculus 1-3 before leaving.  I'm worried I have forgotten all of my calculus and won't be able to perform in my upcoming classes.  What is the best way to get caught up and what are some web sites that will help me catch up?

Thanks

Comment: Don't worry, it's like riding a bicycle! (Something I never learned to do properly!)

Comment: I wish I could accept all of your answers but I chose JohnJPershing's because I really liked patrickJMT.  Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal favorite is [patrickJMT](http://patrickjmt.com/) (just math tutorials) He has more than just calc, but his 100+ full in depth calculus videos helped me through my classes. Khan Academy is good too, but honestly they are dont go in depth enough.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to thoroughly review your trigonometry and algebra.  I have been a teaching assistant for many calculus classes and I have found through experience that many students have trouble with calculus because they have not mastered the prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

Khan Academy is probably the best site. It's interactive. There are videos and drills that you can use to test your chops. [Link](https://www.khanacademy.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Paul's Online Notes are pretty good.
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx

Answer (score 0):

All 3 mentioned, I find great for different things. Khan Academy for developing some insight (if you have forgotten the overarching idea), PatrickJMT for lots of examples of how to actually do questions, and Paul's Online Notes are also great for reading.